# Variable length input for LSTM autoencoder- Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I am trying an autoencoder model with LSTM layers in Keras for text outlier detection. I have encoded every sentence into a sequence of numbers, with each number representing a letter.

So far I have already trained a model with a fixed-length input, by padding zeros to each of the 4000 sequences up to maxlength = 40 thus training the model with a [4000,40,1] shaped array ([batch_size, timesteps, features]).

Now I am wondering how I can use such an autoencoder model without padding zeros to each sequence (sentence) thus training and predicting with the actual size of each sentence (sequence).

At the moment I have standardized every sequence so my train data (x_train) is a list of arrays and every array in list represents a standardized sequence of numbers of different lengths.

To input this data to the LSTM model I am trying to reshape into 3d array with:

```py
x_train=np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 1, 1))
```

not sure if this is correct though.

My model looks like this (I've removed the input_shape parameter so the model can accept variable-length input):

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(15, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(5, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(15, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add((Dense(1,activation='tanh')))
```

Then when trying to compile and train the model

```py
nb_epoch = 10
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="text_model.h5",
                               verbose=0,
                               save_best_only=True)

es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss')

history = model.fit(x_train, x_train,
                    epochs=nb_epoch,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_data=(x_test, x_test),
                    verbose=0,
                    callbacks=[checkpointer,es_callback])
```

I get error : "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

My model summary is the following:

```py
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 20)             1760      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 15)             2160      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_8 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 5)              420       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_9 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 15)             1260      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_10 (LSTM)               (None, 1, 20)             2880      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1, 1)              21        
=================================================================
Total params: 8,501
Trainable params: 8,501
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

So my question is if it's possible to train and predict with variable-length input sequence in an LSTM autoencoder model.

And if my thinking process on text outlier detection using such a model architecture is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Padding still has to be done such that the input can be 3d array(tensor), but Keras actually provides [masking](https://keras.io/layers/core/#masking) layer for you to ignore the padded 0s in the input tensor. So that the model will not be affected by the paddings.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Masking

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(timesteps, features)))
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='tanh',return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(15, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(5, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(15, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(20, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add((Dense(1,activation='tanh')))
```